# PHP using double quotes or single quotes in a function difference

Tags: php

Hey I have some simple php/html:

```
<?php
  if( $_POST["name"] || $_POST["age"] )
  {
     echo "Welcome ". $_POST['name']. "<br />";
     echo "You are ". $_POST['age']. " years old.";
     exit();
  }
?>
<html>
<body>


  <form action="<?php $_PHP_SELF ?>" method="POST">
  Name: <input type="text" name="name" />
  Age: <input type="text" name="age" />
  <input type="submit" />
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

I don't understand why on the second line we use double quotes i.e. `$_POST["name"]` but in the echo statement we use $_POST['name'], could someone tell me why these are different? Completely new to PHP...

Comment: Both are same, as you are working with array index

Comment: So these are used to access the array right? I am using the key name or age. so using double quotes, single quotes or non at all will give the same result. Is that right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It doesn't really matter what quotes you choose. There are several discussions about performance. Indeed double quotes are a tiny bit slower. But the difference is minimal even at 100,000+ iterations.

The only differences are the concenation and escaping:

### Concenation

**Double quotes:**

```
$b = 1;
echo "Test ".$b; // outputs Test 1
echo "Test $b"; // also outputs Test 1
```

**Single quotes:**

```
$b = 2;
echo 'Test '.$b; // outputs Test 2
echo 'Test $b'; // outputs Test $b
```

### Escaping

**Double quotes:**

```
echo "\t";
// outputs actual tab letter
```

**Single quotes**

```
echo '\t';
// outputs \t as plain text.
```

Comment: That's not the only difference. Single quotes also do not handle escape sequences. Try "\n" and '\n';

Comment: Ohh thanks, didn't know that. Ill add that to the answer

Comment: $a = "Test $b";  will call $b variable in variable $a

Comment: Thats what its meant to do

Comment: In my example I am accessing a variable in the array $_POST via the key name or age. Is this right? I noticed that I can also do it without using quotes ie. $_POST[name]. However you cannot write an echo statement like: echo this is me;. Why is this different?

Comment: You shouldn't use it without quotes. PHP will always throw an error and just 'guess' that you meant to use it with quotes cause there is no constant defined for that name

Answer (score 1):

Quite simple.
It is because of **echo**.
You can see that when printing a string you can either use echo 'hello'; or echo "hello";
The fact here is whether you use one you cannot use the same within the variables inside, otherwise php parse it as it was a end of the string.

Simple example:

```
echo 'Hello'.$name.' how are you?';
echo "Hello".$name." how are you?";
```

Asociative array example:

```
echo 'Hello'.$array["name"].' how are you?';
```

If you try to put array['name'] you will see that php gives an error because of parsing.

Hope it helps !

Comment: Correct, but double-quote also reserve escape sequences